# Determine if $\lvert\sin(x)\rvert$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

**Question**

Part (a)
Given the function $$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$$ defined by $$f(x)=\lvert\sin(x)\rvert$$ determine where $f$ is differentiable and find its derivative

My initial idea was to substitute $f(x)$ into the $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$
 but I don't know where to go from after substituting this in, I know the answer is $$\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\lvert\sin(x)\rvert}$$ and it's differentiable for all $x\ne n\pi$ where $n\in \Bbb Z$.

Part (b)
Let $m,n\in \Bbb N$. Given the function $$g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$$ defined by
$$g(x)= \bigl(\sin(x^m)\bigr)^n$$ show that $g$ is differentiable and find its derivative.

My thought process was to show that the limit exists again which in turn show that $g$ is differentiable and would also give me the derivative, however would I need to check both the right and left hand side limits as $x$ approaches $c$ and if there both the same then the derivative exists right?

Comment: For future reference, it is not considered OK to ask multiple questions in the same post. Use a new post if you want to do this. Also, you're more likely to get help if you show what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to use the chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\Big[|x|\Big]=\frac{x}{|x|}$$

With $u=|\sin(x)|$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\Big[|\sin(x)|\Big]=\frac{d}{du}\Big[|u|\Big] \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\Big[\sin(x)\Big]=\frac{u}{|u|} \cdot \cos(x)=\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{|sin(x)|}$$

Now, if you want an explanation of why $\frac{d}{dx}\Big[|x|\Big]=\frac{x}{|x|}$, keep reading.

$|x|$ can be defined in two ways.

The usual way is to use a piecewise function, but there is a much more intuitive way.

$$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$$

Boom. We can now use a super simple application of the chain rule which you could do yourself.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sqrt{x^2}\right]=\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{x}{|x|}$$

Edit: If you want a proof of $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, just use that as your definition of $|x|$, that's what I do.

Comment: I think the command is \Bigg but i'm not sure, see here for more information https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Brackets_and_Parentheses

Comment: Thank you for the way in which you laid this out, i know the chain rule, but i'm just used to doing it straight away for somewhat simple functions for some reason my lecture doesnt teach this course with the $\frac{d}{dx}$ notation. could you also look at this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229959/showing-a-piece-wise-function-is-differentiable-and-finding-its-derivative/2229990?noredirect=1#comment4585434_2229990 i think the question that was set on my mock examination is incorrect or invalid

Comment: Thanks @Gibberish, I will incorporate that in a minute

Comment: no worries, thanks for the help.

Comment: And, @Gibberish, you were right. That question was totally flawed, and is not differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. It is differentiable $\forall n \text{ s.t. } n \in \mathbb{R} \wedge n \geq 1$, but is undefined and therefore not differentiable otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint (a)**: Restricting our attention to the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$,
$$
f(x)=\left|\sin x\right|=\begin{cases}
\sin x & \text{if }x\geq0\\
-\sin x & \text{if }x<0.
\end{cases}
$$
For $f$ to be differentiable at zero, we must have
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}(\sin x)^{\prime}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0-}(-\sin x)^{\prime}
$$
where $\prime$ denotes derivative. However, this is clearly not true
(check).

**Hint (b)**: Have you learned that a composition of differentiable functions
is itself differentiable?

Comment: You mean sin(x) if 0<x<180 and then -sin(x) for 180<x<360, right?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: no, I am using radians. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Abs%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5D

Comment: @parsiad Thank you for this, it makes sense now, i was misunderstanding the question since $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}(\sin x)^{\prime}\ne \lim_{x\rightarrow0-}(-\sin x)^{\prime}$$ then $$f'(0)$$ does not exist?

Comment: sorry, I see now, you start at -pi, not zero. My bad.

Comment: @Gibberish: yes, but you should convince yourself of this fact.

Comment: may i ask why it asks us to find the derivative if it does not exist at 0?

Comment: @Gibberish: it means "determine *where* $f$ is differentiable and find the derivative [at points where it is differentiable]"

Comment: @parsiad sorry i only just seen you're part b hint, and yes we have learned that the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable. same with the product and quotient ?

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=\lvert\sin x\rvert$ is differentiable at every point where $\sin x>0$ or $\sin x<0$, because in those cases it either coincides with $\sin x$ or with $-\sin x$ in a neighborhood of $x$.

Thus the problem is where $\sin x=0$, that is, for $x=n\pi$, where $n$ is an integer.

Now,
$$
\frac{\lvert\sin(n\pi+h)\rvert-\lvert\sin(n\pi)\rvert}{h}=
\frac{\lvert\sin h\rvert}{h}
$$
by well known trigonometric identities. Look at the limits from the left and from the right.

For part (b) use the chain rule.

Comment: when using the chain rule would i need to use the definition of a derivative? i,e would i use $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$

Comment: and does $$\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{|\sin(h)|}{h}=1$$ ?

Comment: @Gibberish Why should use the definition? The chain rule is a theorem based on it, you can use it whenever it can be applied, such as in this case. And yes, that limit is $1$.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for some reason i thought i would need to use it. also i've seen a lot of examples of proving differentiability at a certain point, in a case where no point is given is it safe to make an arbitrary point and show that the function is differentiable there?