# Showing a piece wise function is differentiable and finding it's derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Show that from the definition that g is differentiable and find its derivative $g'
$
$$g:x\mapsto \begin{cases} 
     \sqrt{x} & x< 0        
\\\frac{x}{2} & x\geq1
   \end{cases}$$
My attempt For $x<0$ 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sqrt{x}-0}{x}$$$$=\lim_{x\to 0^-}x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$ which is undefined?

For $x\geq 1$ we have that $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-1}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{2(x-1)}{4(x-1)}$$ $$=\frac{2}{4}$$ which exists thus $$f'(1)=\frac{2}{4}$$. my question is, is my approach correcT? and is there an error in the question, should the second condition be $x>0$ or do i need to calculate both sides of the limit for each case $x<0$ and $x\geq 1$

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The function $\sqrt x$ is undefined for $x<0$, and you haven't defined the function on $[0,1)$ at all.

Comment: Are you saying the question doesnt make sense or my solution?, i'm just following the examples i have but none of them have been like this

Comment: note i've typed the question as on the mock examinaation, i think i will email the lecturer?

Comment: the domain is $(0,\infty)$ and the codomain was the $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Elliot G points out the shortcomings in the mathematics of the problem statement. It seems beyond salvage. But perhaps we can craft a workable substitute.

Were you meant to look at $x=4$ where the functions $\sqrt{x}$ and $\frac{x}{2}$ have the same value? But the slopes are unequal, so we can't form a continuous derivative.

Perhaps another example will help. Consider the function
$$
\begin{align}
 f(x) =  
\begin{cases}
x^{3} & x <0 \\
x^{2} & x \ge 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
The function and its derivative are continuous. The point of interest is the origin. You can construct an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument to approach from the right and from the left. The sequences approach the same value for the function. Similarly, you can apply this approach to show that the derivatives from the right and the left converge to the same value.

Comment: so you are confirming that the question is incorrect? i thought it was strange that $x<0$ and $x\geq 1$ the question was stated as i wrote, so i'm assuming my lecturer has made a mistake on the problem sheet & for your problem, could we just consider the limits $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{x^3-0}{x}=0^2=0$$ and if this is equal to $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2-0}{x}=0$$  then the function $f(x)$ is differential at 0.

Comment: @Elliot G was as accurate as he was succinct. If that was written by a lecturer, considering switching sections. Your derivatives should look like $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$.

Comment: i thought there was an alternative $$\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$$ Source: Fundementals of mathematical analysis page 166 (second edition) rod haggarty , and sorry i'm not great at english, is the question incorrect? if so i will need to notify the lecturer as it was recently set.

Comment: That form will work, too. Just wanted to make sure. (Learning mathematics in a second language is an admirable undertaking.)

Comment: so, $f(c)=c^3$ in both cases so i assume that for your example the function $f(x)$ is differentiable at 0 i,e $f'(0)=0$ for both cases,$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{x^3-c^3}{x-c}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{(x-c)(x^2+c^2+xc)}{x-c}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0^-}(x^2+c^2+xc)=c^2$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^3-c^3}{x-c}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{(x-c)(x^2+c^2+xc)}{x-c}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x^2+c^2+xc)=c^2$$ Thus $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=0$$ since in this case $c=0$ as $x\to 0^{+,-}$